# Python PySerial FlushInput not working

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am new to programming and serial communication, so forgive me for likely messing up something simple.

The script I am writing is reading temperature data sent via serial port from an Arduino. When it first loads up, the Arduino sketch sends a "menu" with options for reading, writing, and clearing EEPROM.

When I load the python script, sometimes it works well enough. Other times, it just doesn't read anything. And other times, it floods my terminal with temp reading data for about 5 seconds, then it sends the menu and acts normally.

I have added the flushinput and time delays, but to no avail.

Another quick question: if I'm in the while loop collecting data from serial, which is without end, how would I be able to enter a command to pause and switch to another part of the program without interrupting the data stream? For example, if I'm collecting data from the temp sensor and using serial to do real-time plotting of temp vs time, but I want to be able to interrupt this at anytime to stop writing and switch to reading (saving data to .txt file). How could this be done?

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Here is the Python code:

```
import serial
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/tty.usbmodem1421', 9600, timeout = 5)
ser.flushInput()
ser.flushOutput()
time.sleep(0.1)


print ("Connected to serial port: {}".format(ser.name))


def Menu():
data_left = 1

while (data_left != 0):
    print(ser.readline())
    time.sleep(.1)
    data_left = ser.inWaiting()

return

def RealTimePlot(y, count, k, minPlot, maxPlot):
    //stuff
def WriteData(mode, plotData = 'n'):
    //stuff
def ReadData(mode):
    //stuff

def main():

launch = 0
plotData = ProgramIntro()

time.sleep(1)
Menu()

mode = raw_input("> ")

while (1):


    if ((mode == "end") or (mode == 'exit')) :
        ser.close()
        exit()

    elif (mode == 'm'):

        ser.write(mode)
        time.sleep(1)
        Menu()
        mode = raw_input("> ")
        if (mode == 'm'):
            print("Already at menu. Would you like to:")
            print("[w]rite")
            print("[r]ead")
            print("[c]lear")

    elif (mode == 'w'):
        count = 0
        WriteData(mode, plotData)
        #mode = PauseProgram()


    elif (mode == 'r'):

        ReadData(mode)
        #mode = PauseProgram()


    elif (mode == 'c'):

        ser.write(mode)
        time.sleep(1)

        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out = ser.readline()
            print(out)
            time.sleep(0.1)

        mode = 'm'



print("Goodbye!")


#Closes the connection
ser.close()
```

And Arduino Code:

```
// References
// https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sik-experiment-guide-for-arduino---v32/experiment-7-reading-a-temperature-sensor
// https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/EEPROMWrite
// https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/EEPROMRead
//
// The following may be useful to read on storing EEPROM data:
// http://www.vernier.com/engineering/arduino/store-data-eeprom/
//

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <EEPROM.h>


// Define pins
const int writePin = 5;
const int readPin = 9;
const int pausePin = 7;
const int collectDataBtn = 11;
const int RTPin = 3;
const int sensorPin = A0;   // Temperature Pin

char RTData;
int j = 0;






// SETUP of Serial port and PINS for LED
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(writePin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RTPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(readPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pausePin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(sensorPin, INPUT);
  pinMode(collectDataBtn, INPUT);

  while(Serial.available())
      Serial.read();
}







char mode = 'm';
char prevMode = 'm';

int k = 0;

// MAIN LOOP
void loop() {

    while (j == 0) {
        if (k == 0) {
            Serial.print("Would you like to plot real-time data? (y/n) ");
            k++;
        }

        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
            RTData = Serial.read();

            if (RTData == 'y') {
                digitalWrite(RTPin, HIGH);
                j++;
            }
            else {
                j++;
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    switch (mode) {

        // MENU mode
        case 'm':
        case 'M':
            // Set LEDs to indicate menu mode
            digitalWrite(writePin, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(readPin, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(pausePin, LOW);

            // Print menu to serial port
            PrintMenu();
            while (mode == 'm') {
                if (Serial.available() > 0) {
                    prevMode = mode;
                    mode = Serial.read();
                }
            }
            break;

        // WRITE mode
        case 'w':
        case 'W':

            Serial.println("Entering WRITE mode...");

            mode = WriteData(sensorPin, collectDataBtn);
            break;

        // READ mode
        case 'r':
        case 'R':

            // Sets LEDs to indicate READ mode
            digitalWrite(writePin, LOW);
            digitalWrite(readPin, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(pausePin, LOW);

            Serial.println("Entering READ mode...");

            mode = ReadData(sensorPin, prevMode);
            break;

        // CLEAR eeprom mode
        case 'c':
        case 'C':
            Serial.println("Clearing EEPROM...");

            ClearEEPROM();

            Serial.println("EEPROM cleared!");
            Serial.println("Returning to menu...\n\n");
            mode = 'm';
            break;

        // PAUSE mode
        default:
            // Sets LEDs to indicate PAUSE mode
            digitalWrite(writePin, LOW);
            digitalWrite(readPin, LOW);
            digitalWrite(pausePin, HIGH);

            mode = 'p';

            mode = PauseMode(mode);
            break;
    }

} // END void loop


void ClearEEPROM(void) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < EEPROM.length() ; i++) {

      if ((i % 100 == 0) || (i % 50 == 0)) {
          digitalWrite(writePin, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(readPin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(pausePin, LOW);
      }
      else {
          digitalWrite(writePin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(readPin, LOW);
          digitalWrite(pausePin, HIGH);

      }

      EEPROM.write(i, 0);
    }
    return;
}





char CheckModeChange(void) {

  if (Serial.available() > 0) {

      // read the incoming char:
      prevMode = mode;
      mode = Serial.read();

   }
   return mode;

}



void PrintMenu(void) {
  Serial.println("\n");
  Serial.println("  **  Menu  **    ");
  Serial.println("------------------");
  Serial.println("|  [W]rite Data   |");
  Serial.println("|  [R]ead  Data   |");
  Serial.println("|  [C]lear Data   |");
  Serial.println("------------------");
  Serial.println("Enter [m]enu to return to menu at any point,");
  Serial.println("or press any other key to pause during any point of the program.");

  return;
}




char PauseMode(char mode){

    Serial.println("Program Paused. Choose an option from the following to continue: ");
    Serial.println("[m]enu");
    Serial.println("[w]rite");
    Serial.println("[r]ead");
    Serial.println("[c]lear \n");

    while (mode == 'p') {
        if (Serial.available() > 0) {
            mode = Serial.read();
        }
    }

    return mode;

}




char WriteData(int sensorPin, int collectDataBtn) {

    // Declarations
    int cnt, voltVal;
    int addr = 0;   // Initializes address at 0 for EEPROM
    int beginData = 0;
    float voltage, degreesC;
    char mode = 'w';

    // Collect data when button pushed. This will be replaced by z-axis acceleration threshold
    // of rocket.
    Serial.println("Waiting for launch to begin...");
    while (beginData == 0) {

        if (cnt > 20000) {
          cnt = 0;
        }

        else if (cnt < 10000) {
            digitalWrite(writePin, LOW);
            digitalWrite(readPin, LOW);
            digitalWrite(pausePin, LOW);
        }
        else {
            digitalWrite(writePin, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(readPin, LOW);
            digitalWrite(pausePin, LOW);
        }
        cnt++;

        if (digitalRead(collectDataBtn) == HIGH) {
          beginData = 1;
        }

        prevMode = mode;
        mode = CheckModeChange();
        if (prevMode != mode) {
            beginData = 1;
        }


    }

    digitalWrite(writePin, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(readPin, LOW);
    digitalWrite(pausePin, LOW);
    // Write Data loop
    while (mode == 'w') {
        // First we'll measure the voltage at the analog pin. Normally
        // we'd use analogRead(), which returns a number from 0 to 1023.
        // Here we've written a function (further down) called
        // getVoltage() that returns the true voltage (0 to 5 Volts)
        // present on an analog input pin.
        voltage = getVoltage(sensorPin);

        // Now we'll convert the voltage to degrees Celsius.
        // This formula comes from the temperature sensor datasheet:
        // CONVERT IN PYTHON SCRIPT
        // degreesC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100.0;
        //Serial.print("Address[");
        //Serial.print(addr);
        //Serial.print("]: \t");
        Serial.println(voltage);
        /***
          Write the value to the appropriate byte of the EEPROM.
          these values will remain there when the board is
          turned off.
        ***/

        // Convert for storage to EEPROM
        voltVal = (voltage * 10000) / 4;

        // Write to EEPROM
        EEPROM.write(addr, voltVal);


        /***
          Advance to the next address, when at the end restart at the beginning.

          Larger AVR processors have larger EEPROM sizes, E.g:
          - Arduno Duemilanove: 512b EEPROM storage.
          - Arduino Uno:        1kb EEPROM storage.
          - Arduino Mega:       4kb EEPROM storage.

          Rather than hard-coding the length, you should use the pre-provided length function.
          This will make your code portable to all AVR processors.
        ***/

        addr = addr + 1;


        /***
          As the EEPROM sizes are powers of two, wrapping (preventing overflow) of an
          EEPROM address is also doable by a bitwise and of the length - 1.

          ++addr &= EEPROM.length() - 1;
        ***/

        // Check for mode change
        mode = CheckModeChange();
        delay(100);
    }

    return mode;
}






char ReadData(int Pin, char prevMode) {

    // Declarations
    byte value;
    float voltageVal, voltage, degreesC;
    int addr = 0;
    char mode = 'r';

    // Checks previous mode. If previous mode was write, now that we are reading
    // we should reset the EEPROM address to 0 so we can read from the beginning.

    if ( (prevMode == 'w') || (prevMode == 'W') ) {
        addr = 0;
    }


    while (mode == 'r') {
        value = EEPROM.read(addr);

        voltageVal = value;

        voltage = voltageVal * 4 / 10000;
        //Serial.print("Voltage: ");
        //Serial.print("\t");
        //Serial.println(voltage);

        degreesC = (voltage - 0.5) * 100.0;
        //Serial.print("Degrees C: ");
        //Serial.print("\t");


        //Serial.print("Address[");
        //Serial.print(addr);
        //Serial.print("]: \t");
        Serial.println(degreesC);


        /***
          Advance to the next address, when at the end restart at the beginning.

          Larger AVR processors have larger EEPROM sizes, E.g:
          - Arduno Duemilanove: 512b EEPROM storage.
          - Arduino Uno:        1kb EEPROM storage.
          - Arduino Mega:       4kb EEPROM storage.

          Rather than hard-coding the length, you should use the pre-provided length function.
          This will make your code portable to all AVR processors.
        ***/
        addr = addr + 1;
        if (addr == EEPROM.length()) {
          addr = 0;
        }
        // Check for mode change
        mode = CheckModeChange();

        delay(100);
    }

    return mode;
}









float getVoltage(int pin) {
    // This function has one input parameter, the analog pin number
    // to read. You might notice that this function does not have
    // "void" in front of it; this is because it returns a floating-
    // point value, which is the true voltage on that pin (0 to 5V).


    return (analogRead(pin) * 0.004882814);
    // This equation converts the 0 to 1023 value that analogRead()
    // returns, into a 0.0 to 5.0 value that is the true voltage
    // being read at that pin.
}
```

Comment: Can you please also add the Arduino code to see how the communication is handled on that side?

Comment: Sure. It is uploaded now. Thanks!